# Parse remote push notification service unavailable iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I'm having an issue with Remote push notifications everything is Installed but when i try to send a push notifications it says 
`[Error]: Client-initiated push isn't enabled.`

so i went to `Parse/appName/Settings/Push` when i try to enable Client Push notification it says Service Unavailable.

i thought it's because i didn't upload a certificate, then  i created & Uploaded a certificate but No luck.

i checked their Status, everything is Working..

am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

change the name of your application and try again.
for example, I had "game" and changed to "ggame" in my application and it worked.